# Eviar un valor de c# ( ASP.Net MVC ) a Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

Hola Estoy intentando mandar una variable a mi JavaScript para así poder alimentar los Event de mi Full Calendar pero no logro mandar la variable

Controlador

```
public ActionResult Index()
{


    var Lista = db.Eq_tblMantenimientos.Select(a => new
    {
        a.id,
        title= a.Descripcion,
        start= a.FechaInicio,
        end= a.FechaFin

    }).ToArray();

    string jsonCalendar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lista);

    return View();
}
```

aqui mando mi lista string JsonCalendar en formato String

Comment: en realidad ahi no estas mandando la lista, solo estas mandando un return view, para mandar esa variable tienes que crear un modelo el cual tenga una variable tipo string y declarar el modelo dentro de tu controllador y luego igualarle tu jsonCalendar y luego hacer un return view(Modelo) y en tu vista Index agregar la conexion con el modelo que creaste

Comment: En realidad tienes toda la razon Cambie el action result por un JsonResult y lo mande a ajax con un return Json :D

Comment: Muy bien, te recomiendo poner como lograste resolver tu problema en una respuesta para si a alguien le pasa lo mismo tenga la respuesta saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Calendar()
{
var Lista = db.Eq_tblMantenimientos.Select(a => new
    {
        a.id,
        title= a.Descripcion,
        start= a.FechaInicio,
        end= a.FechaFin

    }).ToList();

    return Json(Lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

En la vista deberias a la variable events = []
pasarle datos recorriendola, ejemplo:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        GetCalendar();
    });

    function GetCalendar(){
        $.get('/controlador/Calendar').done(function(data){
        var events = [];

        $.each(data, function (idx, elem){

            events.push({
                    'id': elem.Id,
                    'tittle': elem.Title,
                    'star': elem.Start,
                    'end': elem.End
                });
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

de esa manera irias pasando los datos realmente, lo demas son los datos que trae ese plugin de calendar, recuerda que el formato de fecha reconocido por calendar es ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio

Comment: Me alegra mucho haberte sido de ayuda hermano.